# java.lang.NullPointerException after code execution

Tags: jsp

I have these 2 pages, after i enter data into the form and submit it it writes:

> Založení letadla
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

what can I do with this problem....because user written manuals that can be googled does not help me :(

### admin.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="vlozit.jsp">
<p>Založit Letadlo</p><br>
<table>
<tr><td>ID:</td>           <td><input type="text" name="id"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Model letadla:</td><td><input type="text" name="model"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Počet sedadel:</td><td><input type="text" name="sedadel"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Založit letadlo">

</form>
</body>
```

### and the vlozit.php

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Administrace</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <H1>Založení letadla</H1>

    <%




String ID= request.getParameter("id");
String model = request.getParameter("model");
String sedadel = request.getParameter("sedadel");

try{



        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");


        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ATBS", "CENTOS", "Shaman123");
if(conn != null){


        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

        String command = "INSERT INTO letadlo (ID, model, sedadel) VALUES ('"+ID+"', '"+model+"', '"+sedadel+"')";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(command);
        if(ps != null){
        ps.execute();}}

conn.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
out.println(e); 
}



    %>
</BODY>
```

Comment: Please show the stacktrace

Comment: Exception Stacktrace?

Comment: i am jsp beginner ...how to show the stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Connection object for null before calling methods on it.

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ATBS", "CENTOS", "Shaman123");

if(conn != null)
{
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

        String command = "INSERT INTO letadlo (ID, model, sedadel) VALUES ('"+ID+"', '"+model+"', '"+sedadel+"')";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(command);

        ps.execute();

        conn.close();     //Ideally it should be closed inside finally.
}
```

Ideally `Connection` and `PrepareStatement` should be closed inside `finally` block.

Comment: tried your idea with if(conn != null) but still java.lang.NullPointerException  :(

Comment: Why are you creating PreparedStatement and Statement both. i think Statement is not needed.